# unable to start debugging. failures to process configuration file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

when I want start my project in vs 2019 i see this error:
unable to start debugging.failures to process configuration file. try to start this application. if failures continue, try to repair your installation.

I tested in windows form application, console application and asp Core.

My project will be built but will not start from visual studio 2019.

I repair and update vs 2019 but also I have this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Visual Studio is installed by an online installer, you will often run into problems. It is better to install Visual Studio with an authorized IP or find a full version of it without the need for online installation. You can reinstall vs

Answer (score 0):

This error was due to incomplete installation of Visual Studio. Repair, update, or reinstall Visual Studio to resolve this issue.